# ObjC to Swift array loop , need help please

Tags: objective-c, arrays, swift

I have the following loop in ObjC:  myArray is a 2D array.

```
for (NSArray *newArray in myArray) {

    for (int i = 0; i < newArray.count; i++) {

        NSArray *points = [newArray[i] componentsSeparatedByString:@","];
  }
}...
```

I am trying to do the same thing using **Swift** but am struggling to find a way to get componentsSeperatedByString:

```
for newArray in myArray {

        for i in 0..<newArray.count {
            var pnts:NSArray = newArray[i].componentsSeparatedByString(",")
        }
    }
```

Comment: It might help if you showed the declaration of myArray as well as some medication of what the actual problem is.

Comment: myArray is a 2d array of  objects and their vectors.  I am then looping through each object and pulling out each of it's vectors to test against so each element of newArray is a string vectory eg. "150.10 , 310.00"  in swift I can't seem to find a method to separate the vectors.  It will let me do newArray.componentsSeparatedByString(",")   but not newArray[I].componentsSeperatedByString(",")

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first step is to convert your `NSArray` to have the proper type, in this case it looks like you want:

```
if let array = myArray as? [[String]] {
}
```

Then you have a number of options, the most effective of which is probably a nested iteration:

```
let myArray = NSArray(arrayLiteral:
    NSArray(arrayLiteral: "150.10,310.20"),
    NSArray(arrayLiteral: "400.10,310.20", "100,200")
)

if let source = myArray as? [[String]] {
    for array in source {
        for element in array {
            print(element.componentsSeparatedByString(","))
        }
    }
}
// -> ["150.10", "310.20"]
//    ["400.10", "310.20"]
//    ["100", "200"]
```

If all you're wanting to do is extract the points, you can use map:

```
if let source = myArray as? [[String]] {
    print(source.map {
        $0.map { $0.componentsSeparatedByString(",") }
        }
    )
}    
// -> [[["150.10", "310.20"]], [["400.10", "310.20"], ["100", "200"]]]
```

If you want to collapse the points into a single array, you can use flatMap, as pointed out by Helium, which will turn the array of arrays, into a simple array:

```
if let source = myArray as? [[String]] {
    print(source.flatMap {
        $0.map { $0.componentsSeparatedByString(",") }
        }
    )
}
// -> [["150.10", "310.20"], ["400.10", "310.20"], ["100", "200"]]
```

Of course, you can also extract it as [[Double]] instead of [[String]] by using yet another map call:

```
if let source = myArray as? [[String]] {
    print(source.map {
        $0.map { $0.componentsSeparatedByString(",").map { Double($0)! } }
    })
}
// -> [[150.1, 310.2], [400.1, 310.2], [100.0, 200.0]]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want the pnts, you can use flatmap, which will flatten the 2D array into a single array with the points.

```
let pnts = myArray.flatMap { array in
            array.map { object in
            object.componentsSeparatedByString(",") 
        }
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be doing the same thing as the original code.  Note that points is declared local to the scope, so it doesn't seem to be accumulating.

Comment: Basically what I am trying to do is use a for loop to loop through an Array of Vectors stored as strings: "150.10, 310.20"  ,  "400.10,  310.20" , etc..  I my swift loop above the newArray is only seen as an element and not an array so I cant do newArray[I].componentsSeperatedByString(",")